# Python selenium chromedriver error: "Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed."

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting this error while running selenium in ec2 with python 3.7:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_sellinum.py", line 55, in <module>
    run()
  File "test_sellinum.py", line 29, in run
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    keep_alive,
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 64, in __init__
    options=options,
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 290, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 345, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55caa7c53e23 <unknown>
#1 0x55caa797c7a7 <unknown>
#2 0x55caa79a750a <unknown>
#3 0x55caa79a4a25 <unknown>
#4 0x55caa79e4d92 <unknown>
#5 0x55caa79e43af <unknown>
#6 0x55caa79dbde3 <unknown>
#7 0x55caa79afa7b <unknown>
#8 0x55caa79b081e <unknown>
#9 0x55caa7c15638 <unknown>
#10 0x55caa7c19507 <unknown>
#11 0x55caa7c23c4c <unknown>
#12 0x55caa7c1a136 <unknown>
#13 0x55caa7be89cf <unknown>
#14 0x55caa7c3db98 <unknown>
#15 0x55caa7c3dd68 <unknown>
#16 0x55caa7c4ccb3 <unknown>
#17 0x7f02d4ce244b start_thread
```

I use the following code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


def run():
    service = Service()
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

My chromedriver version is:

```
$ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 116.0.5845.96 (1a391816688002153ef791ffe60d9e899a71a037-refs/branch-heads/5845@{#1382})
```

and my chrome browser version is:

```
$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 116.0.5845.179
```

I have gone through all stack overflow answers I could find, but nothing worked for me. I think it might be an issue with selenium.